# Can I take a word out of Array of strings?

Tags: arrays, c, string, arrayofstring

I am writing the following string in the main function:

`char* dict[] = { "ball", "aba", "bla" };`

My question is:

Am I able to take a whole word out of this string?

For example, if I want to copy the whole word, can I do something like this:
`str[j] = dict[i];`
(in some loop of course)

It is important to note that I can't use the `#include<string.h>` library, due to the requirements of the question

Comment: Before diving in further, do you understand that isn't a "array of strings", it's an array of *pointer-to-char* ? It's important. Further making copies of a "whole word" can take on different meaning, depending on whether you want to copy the *pointer* to string data vs. copy the string data itself. Assuming `str` is an array of `char*`, `str[j] = dict[i]` can work, but will not make a copy of the string data as you may desire; it will simply copy the pointer to that data to another location, thereby having multiple pointers referring to the same underlying memory.

Comment: @Omer Zohar How is the array str declared? i

Answer (score 2):

A string in C is "Null terminated". It's actually an array of `char` ended by "0".
For example, we have:

```
char* str = "abc";
```

This statement will create an array of 4 elements, `'a', 'b', 'c', 0`, and `str` is the pointer to the array (or pointer to the first element of the array). And the value of `str` is just an address, which is just an integer number. If you copy the string in the way of
`str[j] = dict[i]`
you copy only the address (shallow copy). It will not duplicate the string.

In your case, you create a list of strings (array of char), and `dict[i]` is the pointer to the first element of the i-th string. In other words, we can handle `dict[i]` like a regular string (e.g. `str` in my example).

This is an example of creating a deep copy of your list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* dict[] = { "ball", "aba", "bla" };
    char** copy = (char**) malloc((3) * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        char *shallowCopy = dict[i];
        int length = 0;
        
        while (shallowCopy[length] != 0) length ++; // find the length of the string
        // printf("length: %d\n", length);
        
        char *deepCopy = (char*) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char)); // +1 for null terminated
        deepCopy[length] = 0; // null terminated
        
        while(length >0) deepCopy[--length] = shallowCopy[length];

        copy[i] = deepCopy; // is deepCopy what you mean "to take a whole word out of this string (list)"?
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", copy[i]);
    }   
}
```